# SQL stored procedure modify with IF-ELSE

Tags: sql

This is my stored procedure so far

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[getItems]
  (
    @EventId int,
    @OrgUserId int
  ) AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @BoardBookId int;
SET @BoardBookId = (SELECT bb.BoardbookId FROM Boardbook bb WHERE bb.ItemId = @EventId);

WITH PermissionDeniedAttachments AS
(
    SELECT bbi.CategoryItemId
    FROM BoardbookItem bbi 
    INNER JOIN CategoryItem ci ON ci.CategoryItemId = bbi.CategoryItemId
    WHERE bbi.BoardbookId = @BoardBookId AND bbi.CategoryItemId > 0 AND ci.catID NOT IN (SELECT catID from dbo.f_Categories(@OrgUserId))
)
SELECT 
    bbi.BoardbookId,
    bbi.BoardbookItemId,
    bbi.CategoryItemId,
    bbi.ChBy,
    bbi.ChDt,
    bbi.CrBy,
    bbi.CrDt,
    bbi.DeletedBy,
    bbi.DeletedDt,
    bbi.Description,
    bbi.Duration,
    bbi.ParentBoardbookItemId,
    bbi.SortOrder,
    bbi.Title,
    bbi.Resolutions,
    bbi.Presenter,
    bbi.BoardbookItemType,
    u1.Name_FirstLast as [ItemCreatedByName],
    u2.Name_FirstLast as [ItemChangedByName],
    CAST(CASE WHEN ci.deletedDt IS NULL THEN 0
                      ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS Deleted,
    i.itemType as [DocType],
    ISNULL(ci.catID, 0) AS CatId,
    ISNULL(ci.itemID, 0) AS ItemId,
    d.docID as docId,
    d.docPages as DocPages,
    d.docPwdProtected AS HasPassword,
    bbi.BoardbookItemTypeCustom
from BoardbookItem bbi 
LEFT JOIN Users u1 on u1.UserName=bbi.CrBy
LEFT JOIN Users u2 on u2.UserName=bbi.ChBy
LEFT OUTER JOIN CategoryItem ci ON bbi.CategoryItemId IS NOT NULL AND bbi.CategoryItemId = ci.CategoryItemId
LEFT JOIN Item i ON ci.itemID = i.itemID
LEFT JOIN Documents d on d.docID = bbi.DocId
          where bbi.BoardbookId=@BoardBookId  AND bbi.DeletedDt IS NULL AND 
        (bbi.CategoryItemId IS NULL OR bbi.CategoryItemId NOT IN (Select CategoryItemId from PermissionDeniedAttachments))
```

Now what I want is to put a `var @submenuitem bit` and test it...
So, if `@submenuitem = 0` I will have as response the same effect that I am getting now, 
but if `@submenuitem = 1` I want to have one more check in the "where" for ex.
`'AND bbi.ParentBoardbookItemId='0'`

It seems that it is possible to be done with `IF ELSE` statements BUT unfortunately I can not do it the right way

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making this simple change to your `WHERE` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN Documents d on d.docID = bbi.DocId
      where bbi.BoardbookId=@BoardBookId  AND bbi.DeletedDt IS NULL AND 
    (bbi.CategoryItemId IS NULL OR bbi.CategoryItemId NOT IN (Select CategoryItemId from PermissionDeniedAttachments)
      AND (@submenuitem = 0 OR bbi.ParentBoardbookItemId='0')
```

Answer (score 6):

It is definitely possible without `if... else` statement.

Just add this to `where` condition

```
AND ((bbi.ParentBoardbookItemId='0' and @submenuitem = 1) or @submenuitem = 0)
```

And it will work as you've described.

Comment: Thank you! It looks simple and I am not getting erros. I am going to test it from the client now (front-end)

Comment: This condition is overly complex.  It can simply be `AND (@submenuitem = 0 OR bbi.ParentBoardbookItemId='0')`

Comment: @GeorgiosDeliandreadis If performance is a concern, test. I've found ORs add significant overheard. A work around is to use a UNION and duplicate the query with the top being one side of the OR and the bottom being the second side of the OR.

Comment: @BrianRudolph It may be smaller, but there is a loss of intent that makes it less maintainable. I recommend writing it as Andy had.

Comment: @Ghost Given your previous comment regarding performance, I suspect you will agree when I say that this is why code `#comments` exist.